# PHP HTTP_REFERER and anchor tag href

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the referer url on destination website by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

example.com

```
<a href="example2.com">Click Me</a>
<a href="example2.com/page/2">Click Me</a>
<a href="example2.com/page/3">Click Me</a>
<a href="example2.com/page/4">Click Me</a>
```

example2.com

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

The result is blank.  I clicked on the link.  How do i solve this?  Can `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` work with external domains?

Answer (score 2):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

To prevent this error try

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

OR

```
echo isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

It cant be relied upon.

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

[PHP Manuel](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)